# distance formula proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\vec u$ be a point in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and let $r$ be a positive number. Suppose that the points $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$ are at a distance less than $r$ from the point $\vec u$. Prove that if $0\leq t\leq 1$, then the point $t\vec v +(1-t)\vec w$ is also at a distance less that $r$ from $\vec u$.

All I know is that $\|\vec v-\vec u\|<r$ and $\|\vec w-\vec u\|<r$. And I want to show that $\|t\vec v +(1-t)\vec w-\vec u\|<r$. I tried doing this which was $\|t\vec v +(1-t)\vec w-\vec u\|=\|t\vec v +(1-t)\vec w-\vec u+\vec u-\vec u\|=\|t\vec v-\vec u\|+\|\vec u-t\vec w\|+\|\vec w-\vec u\|$ But I have no idea how to bound this. Any hints would be a great help thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Triangle inequality. $||(tv + (1-t) w) - u|| = || t (v - u) + (1-t) (w-u)|| \leq ||t (v-u)|| + ||(1-t) (w-u)|| = t ||v-u|| + (1-t) ||w-u|| \leq t r + (1-t) r = r$.

(if $||v-u|| < r$ and $||w-u||<r$, the last inequality can be replaced with a strict one)

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful.